# NodeJs: How to create a random delay between 1-3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I have a use case, where I need to have a random delay between 1 - 3 seconds, before calling my next function.

I tried using the setTimeout method, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct

```js
let timeInMs = Math.random() * (3000);
console.log('timeInMs => ', timeInMs);

setTimeout(test, timeInMs);

let test = async() => {
  console.log('called')
};
```

Can someone please help with my use case?

Comment: Please don't edit question to add stuff from answer. The issue is test is being called before declaration and your edit fix the problem, which will make the answer invalid

Comment: @SagarV I ran my code in the browser console and found the issue, that's why I edited without checking the immediate answer, it was unintentional, my real worry was if the code is logical enough, as I needed to implement it at work. I got downvoted because of your comment now.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate your `setTimeOut` function into a `Promise`, then you can call it using the async/await syntax:

```
const randomTimeInMs = Math.random() * (3000);

const functionToExecute = (delay) => console.log(`Ended after ${delay}`)

const executeLater = (functionToExecute, delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(functionToExecute(delay))
        }, delay);
    });
}

// If you are in the entry file use following syntax. If you are already in an async function, just call `await executeLater()`
(async function() {
    await executeLater(functionToExecute, randomTimeInMs)
    console.log('Continue through this code after waiting...')
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You the test variable is undefined when `settimeout` is called.

Use functional syntax and it will due to functions scope

```js
let timeInMs = Math.random() * (3000);
console.log('timeInMs => ', timeInMs);

setTimeout(test,timeInMs);

async function test(){
    console.log('called')
};
```

Comment: In your code the `async` keyword in `test` doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let timeInMs = Math.random() * (3000);
console.log('timeInMs => ', timeInMs);
let test = function (){
    console.log('called')
};
setTimeout(test,timeInMs);
```

- It works correct for me!
- And Yes ! the correct way is using setTimeOut Method.

Comment: Same, `async` doesnt do anything

Comment: I will be having this code, inside an async function, so I add await to the Math and setTimeout function as well correct?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Yes if you need it.